# Why won't be SQLite Database update? Adding a Column

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite

I have tried looking though several of the already asked question about this topic but I still can not get my file to work. I think maybe some direct direct help might be just what i need, so I humbly ask the community for help. Thank you for your time

```
public class RemindersDbAdapter {

//
// Database Related Constants
//
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "reminders";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
public static final String KEY_CUSTOMER = "body";
public static final String KEY_DATE_TIME = "reminder_date_time";
public static final String KEY_END_TIME = "reminder_end_time";
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";


private static final String TAG = "ReminderDbAdapter";
private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
private static SQLiteDatabase mDb;

/**
 * Database creation SQL statement
 */
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ("
                + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + KEY_TITLE + " text not null, " 
                + KEY_CUSTOMER + " text not null, " 
                + KEY_DATE_TIME + " text not null);" ;



private final Context mCtx;

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
    {

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);

        //Adding a Column 
     // If you need to add a column
        if (newVersion > oldVersion) 
        {
            //example I tried pulling from the internet
            db.execSQL(
                "ALTER TABLE foo ADD COLUMN new_column INTEGER DEFAULT 0");
        }

        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to upgrade your database simply add the new column in your CREATE statement, then increment the version.

Your code tries to add a column to a table that you have just dropped...

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE); // Delete table
...
db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE foo ADD COLUMN new_column INTEGER DEFAULT 0"); // Won't find the table
```

Simply change this:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ("
                + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + KEY_TITLE + " text not null, " 
                + KEY_CUSTOMER + " text not null, " 
                + KEY_DATE_TIME + " text not null, "
                + "new_column INTEGER DEFAULT 0);" ;
```

Comment: Thank You, it seems I was mistaken in my issue. You see I did not have the add column statement originally, i thought that was how I was supposed to update a datebase for another issue I am having. Thank you for fixing the new issue I caused lol.

Comment: Thank you for the help, it runs now, I am just having an issue with something else now lol.

Comment: Glad you're making progress! If you get stuck post a new question, please include the logcat errors along with the code sample. (They really help!)